# How to use Flutter Webview Plugin for PayPal payment gateway

Tags: flutter, webview, paypal, payment-gateway

How can I integrate a PayPal payment gateway in flutter framework. I tried with web view but not get success. What is the best way for it.

First I tried with access token and RSET API, but there is problem that no user login for payment. My code is below and this code run with [Tryit Editor](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro) successfully

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';

    class PayPalPayment extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _PayPalPaymentState createState() => _PayPalPaymentState();
        
    }

     class _PayPalPaymentState extends State<PayPalPayment> {
     String test = "Test Charge";
     int amount = 100;

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(
      home: WebviewScaffold(
        url: new Uri.dataFromString('''
       <html>
       <head>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
       </head>

      <body>
      <script
        src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=SB_CLIENT_ID">
      </script>
      <script>paypal.Buttons().render('body');</script>
      </body>
       </html>
                ''', mimeType: 'text/html').toString(),      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`SB_CLIENT_ID = My client id`

Comment: The code you posted does not seem to do much. What was the problem you faced?

Comment: Code show white screen in my app but run with Tryit Editor  successfully

Comment: https://github.com/Pikaju/FlutterBraintree tried this?

Comment: Thanks but I think Braintree currently only supports Android.

Comment: @GursewakSingh did you done with paypal integration ? i need your help if you done it with

Comment: please, share experience

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning to handle responses from inside a WebView, you can use webview_flutter plugin and follow this similar [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67347539/2497859).

However, if you're looking for an easier approach, I suggest using Flutter's [`pay`](https://pub.dev/packages/pay) package for handling payment transactions. The package has support for Apple Pay and Google Pay - both of which supports Paypal.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal doesn't support 'WebViews'.   Ref: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/info-security-guidelines/#secure-applications